# Call the global java script function with parameters/arguments from java

Tags: javascript, java, cordova

I'm trying to call the java script global function from java file in cordova. For this I tried with below code.

**Calling function from java file:**

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:hidedOrNot(" + valueString + ")");
```

**Global function in js file:**

```
window.hidedOrNot = function(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

Same function I'm calling from the js file like `hidedOrNot("Calling");` In this case it's working fine. Any one know where I'm doing the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution......

While calling the JS function from JAVA file we have to mention quotes like this

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:hidedOrNot('" + valueString + "')");
```